# Lambda Expression and generic defined only in method

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

Suppose I've a generic interface:

```
interface MyComparable<T extends Comparable<T>>  {
    public int compare(T obj1, T obj2);
}
```

And a method `sort`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
       void sort(List<T> list, MyComparable<T> comp) {
    // sort the list
}
```

I can invoke this method and pass a lambda expression as argument:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
sort(list, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

That will work fine.

But now if I make the interface non-generic, and the method generic:

```
interface MyComparable {
    public <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T obj1, T obj2);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
       void sort(List<T> list, MyComparable comp) {
}
```

And then invoke this like:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
sort(list, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

It doesn't compile. It shows error at lambda expression saying:

> "Target method is generic"

OK, when I compiled it using `javac`, it shows following error:

```
SO.java:20: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
        sort(list, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
            ^
    (argument mismatch; invalid functional descriptor for lambda expression
      method <T#2>(T#2,T#2)int in interface MyComparable is generic)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>,MyComparable)
    T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in method <T#2>compare(T#2,T#2)
1 error
```

From this error message, it seems like compiler is not able to infer the type arguments. Is that the case? If yes, then why is it happening like this?

I tried various ways, searched through the internet. Then I found [this JavaCodeGeeks article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/whats-cooking-in-java-8-project-lambda.html), which shows a way, so I tried:

```
sort(list, <T extends Comparable<T>>(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

which again doesn't work, contrary to what that article claims that it works. Might be possible that it used to work in some initial builds.

So my question is: Is there any way to create lambda expression for a generic method? I can do this using a method reference though, by creating a method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T obj1, T obj2) {
    return obj1.compareTo(obj2);
}
```

in some class say `SO`, and pass it as:

```
sort(list, SO::compare);
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can't use a *lambda expression* for a *functional interface*, if the method in the *functional interface* has *type parameters*. See [section §15.27.3 in JLS8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3):

> A lambda expression is compatible [..] with a target type *T* if *T* is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is **congruent** with the function type of [..] T. [..] A lambda expression is **congruent** with a function type if all of the following are
>   true:
>
> - The function type has *no type parameters*.
> - [..]

Comment: However, this restriction does not apply to *method references* to generic methods.  You can use a method reference to a generic method with a generic functional interface.

Comment: I'm sure there's a good reason for this restriction. What is it?

Comment: @Sandro: there is simply no syntax for declaring type parameters for a lambda expression. And such a syntax would be very complicated. Keep in mind that the parser still must be able to tell such a lambda expression with type parameters apart from other legal Java constructs. Thus you have to resort to method references. The target method *can* declare type parameters using an established syntax.

Comment: @Holger still, where type parameters can be auto-deduced, the compiler could decude a capure type as it does when you declare e.g. Set<?> and do type-checks with those captured types. Sure, that makes it impossible to give them as type-parameters in the body, but if you'd need that, resorting to method references is a good alternative

Comment: NB that lambda's are compatible with Generics in many other ways (ways that don't have method type parameters)...

Answer (score 21):

Using method reference, i found other way to pass the argument:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");        
sort(list, Comparable::<String>compareTo);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just point compiler the proper version of generic Comparator with
`(Comparator<String>)`

So the answer will be

`sort(list, (Comparator<String>)(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));`

Comment: `incompatible types: java.util.Comparator<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to MyComparable` and `MyComparable` is not generic (no type) so `(MyComparable<String>)` would not work either

Comment: Dont know how you are typing the code @CarlosHeuberger, but it works for me very well, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: @IvanPeralesM. after 2 months... I copied&pasted your code and copied&pasted above line over your sort line - just that, like here: https://ideone.com/YNwBbF ! Are you sure you did type above code exactly? using `Compartor` ?

Comment: No i dont, i use the idea behind the answer, to cast the functional to tell the compile what type it is and it worked.

Comment: @IvanPeralesM. well, then what is your problem with my "typing"? The answer, as it is posted, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?:

```
<T,S>(T t, S s)->...
```

Of what type is this lambda? You couldn't express that in Java and therefore cannot compose this expression in a function application and expressions have to be composable.

For this need to be work you would need support for [Rank2 Types](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Rank2Types) in Java.

Methods are allowed to be generic but therefore you couldn't use them as expressions. They can, however be reduced to lambda expression by specializing all necessary generic types before you can pass them: `ClassName::<TypeName>methodName`

Comment: `"Of what type is this lambda? You couldn't express that in Java..."` The type would be inferred using the context, just as with any other lambda. The type of a lambda isn't explicitly expressed in the lambda itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");        
sort(list, Comparable::<String>compareTo);
```

The `int compareTo (T o)` is not a generic method invocation. Although `Comparable<T>` is an interface with a type. Even if `compareTo` had returned `T`, i.e. `T compareTo (T o)` it still is not a generic method. For it to be a generic method, it needs to include a list of `type parameters`, i.e. `<T> T compareTo (T o)`.