# How to create lambda expression for functional interface having generic method

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have a functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyInterface {
    <T> T modify(Object);
}
```

I can create anonymous class for this interface

```
MyInterface obj = new MyInterface(){
    @Override
    <T> T modify(Object obj){
        return (T) obj
    }
}
```

How to create lambda expression for this.

```
MyInterface obj -> {return (T) obj;};  // ! ERROR as T is undefined
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22588518/1679863

Comment: Factor your lambda into a method, and use a method reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics at method scope cannot be used in lambda expressions. It will throw

> **Illegal lambda expression: Method modify of type MyInterface is generic**

You need to set the generic at class scope.

`@FunctionalInterface 
interface MyInterface<T> {
     T modify(Object obj);
}`

Then use it as follows:

```
MyInterface obj2 = o -> {return o;};
```