# How to avoid "incompatible parameter types in lambda expression" when adding to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code

```
public static List<Integer> topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
  List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

  for (int n : nums) {
    if (!map.containsKey(n)) map.put(n, 1);
    else map.put(n, map.get(n) + 1);
  }

  map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
    .limit(k)
    .forEach((key, value) -> myList.add(key));

  return myList;
}
```

The `forEach` throws the error

```
Error:(20, 16) java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression
```

How can I fix/avoid this error? I'm not quite sure how to apply the answer here that explains the problem: [Lambda Expression and generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588518/lambda-expression-and-generic-method)

Edit:

Given the answer, the correction is to replace the lambda inside the forEach with

```
.forEach((entry) -> myList.add(entry.getKey()));
```

Comment: Sadly Java doesn't allow for tuple unpacking.

Comment: P.S. the question title is terrible - surely the answer is "don't provide incompatible parameters".

Comment: @BoristheSpider sorry this is my first time using lambda's and streams and I wasn't quite sure what the problem was after reading that answer about generics and functional interfaces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588518/lambda-expression-and-generic-method.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: but writing a utility method for converting a `BiConsumer<K,V>` to a `Consumer<Map.Entry<K,V>>` is trivial…

Comment: @Holger sure, and the converse is even easier. Doesn't mean Java unpacks tuples...

Comment: @Boris the Spider: Even worse, Java has no tuples…

Comment: @AR7: note that for your first loop, you can use the stream solution of the accepted answer, but when you use a loop, you can replace `if (!map.containsKey(n)) map.put(n, 1); else map.put(n, map.get(n) + 1);` with `map.merge(n, 1, Integer::sum);`. So there’s not only the Stream API, the Collection API also has lots of useful new methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going about it in a java7-ish way.  Modifying external data structures from inside `forEach` is not how Streams API was meant to be used.  Streams API documentation specifically warns against such use in the Side-Effects section of [`java.util.stream` package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Instead of appending to list or map from inside `forEach`, use `collect`:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.reverseOrder;
import static java.util.Map.Entry.comparingByValue;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;


public static List<Integer> topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
    Map<Integer, Long> freq = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed()
            .collect(groupingBy(x->x, counting()));

    return freq.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(comparingByValue(reverseOrder()))
            .limit(k)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: Ah ok that's very cool. I haven't written Java in about 2 years, which is why it's currently a mix. It makes sense to not have side effects in streams, but I wasn't quite sure what I was doing yet.

Answer (score 6):

`entrySet()` returns a set of `Pair<K, V>`.

`forEach()`'s lambda therefore takes a single parameter of that type; not two integer parameters.