# lambda vs anonymous class

Tags: generics, lambda, java-8, anonymous-class

I have the following piece of code:

```
eventBus.subscribe(new EventBusListener<NavigationEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event<NavigationEvent> event) {
        event.getPayload();
    }
});

eventBus.subscribe(new EventBusListener<NotificationEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event<NotificationEvent> event) {
        event.getPayload();
    }
});
```

IntelliJ tells me that I could replace those two anonymous classes by lambda expressions, like:

```
eventBus.subscribe((EventBusListener<NavigationEvent>) Event::getPayload);
eventBus.subscribe((EventBusListener<NotificationEvent>) Event::getPayload);
```

Compilation works well but at runtime the application crashes with the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve payload type` caused by the `getPayload()` of `Event<T>` class.

What am i missing with `lamdbas` and `generics`?

Comment: use `Event::<NavigationEvent>getPayload` to explicit the type

Comment: as a side note, those are not lambdas, those are function references. It wouldn't work with lambdas, as lambdas can't be used for functional interfaces with generic types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda Expression and generic method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588518/lambda-expression-and-generic-method)

Comment: Thnx for the note. Still get the same error with `Event::<NavigationEvent>getPayload`

Comment: What are you doing with the object returned by the `getPayload()` method?

Comment: Can you share the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @njzk2: `getPayload` is not a generic method, hence, using `Event::<NavigationEvent>getPayload` makes no sense, the type argument will be ignored. And lambda expressions will work, well to the same degree as the method references.

Comment: @Holger now that you mention it, yeah, I read all of that way too fast. it doesn't make sense indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your method references, but the `IllegalArgumentException` hasn’t been thrown by that subsystem either.

It seems the problem is connected to what `eventBus.subscribe` does internally. Due to type erasure, there is only one `subscribe(EventBusListener)` method, not knowing whether you passed in an `EventBusListener<NavigationEvent>` or `EventBusListener<NotificationEvent>`.

As the message “Could not resolve payload type” indicates, it tries to find out the actual payload type anyway, which implies using Reflection. This only works for *reifiable*, i.e. non-generic, types. Your anonymous inner classes are *reifiable* types, not being generic themselves but having a generic super class/interface which can be inspected via [`getGenericSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--) resp. [`getGenericInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces--).

The problem with using method references or lambda expressions in that context, is, that if the interface is generic, the generated runtime class will not be *reifiable*, i.e. you can’t find out the actual type parameter via Reflection. It’s like if you hay written

```
eventBus.subscribe(Event::getPayload);
```

Unless there is an overloaded method allowing you to specify the payload type explicitly, this will not work with lambda expressions or method references.

Depending, how the framework does resolving the type internally, using a *reifiable* interface might work, e.g.

```
interface NavigationEventListener extends EventBusListener<NavigationEvent> {}
…

eventBus.subscribe((NavigationEventListener)Event::getPayload);
```

of course, this would only pay off if you are going to instantiate more than one listener of such a type, otherwise, you could stay with the anonymous inner class (unless their capturing of the `this` instance is your issue).