# Better way to create a stream of functions?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I wish to do lazy evaluation on a list of functions I've defined as follows;

```
Optional<Output> output = Stream.<Function<Input, Optional<Output>>> of(
                    classA::eval, classB::eval, classC::eval)
            .map(f -> f.apply(input))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .findFirst();
```

where as you see, each class (a, b & c) has an `Optional<Output> eval(Input in)` method defined. If I try to do

```
Stream.of(...)....
```

ignoring explicit type, it gives

> T is not a functional interface

compilation error. Not accepting functional interface type for `T` generic type in `.of(T... values)`

---

Is there a snappier way of creating a stream of these functions? I hate to explicitly define `of` method with `Function` and its in-out types. Wouldn't it work in a more generic manner?

This issue stems from the topic of the following question;
[Lambda Expression and generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588518/lambda-expression-and-generic-method)

Comment: Could you please share the signature `ClassA#eval`?

Comment: It is in the question already `Optional<Output> eval(Input in)`, same for all `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC`

Comment: Skipped over that line when reading, mea culpa.

Comment: @Mureinik :) errare humanum est

Comment: There is no better way, the way you're doing it is actually the way it was intended

Comment: Note: you can now use `.flatMap(Optional::stream)` instead of the `isPresent` `get` idiom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can break it into two lines:

```
Stream<Function<Input, Optional<Output>>> stream = Stream
          .of(classA::eval, classB::eval, classC::eval);
Optional<Output> out = stream.map(f -> f.apply(input))
          .filter(Optional::isPresent)
          .map(Optional::get)
          .findFirst();
```

or use casting:

```
Optional<Output> out = Stream.of(
                (<Function<Input, Optional<Output>>>)classA::eval, 
                classB::eval, 
                classC::eval)
        .map(f -> f.apply(input))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .findFirst();
```

but I don't think you can avoid specifying the type of the `Stream` element - `Function<Input, Optional<Output>>` - somewhere, since otherwise the compiler can't infer it from the method references.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way that allows to omit the `Function<Input, Optional<Output>>` type, but it’s not necessarily an improvement

```
Optional<Output> o =
        Stream.concat(Stream.of(input).map(classA::eval),
                Stream.concat(Stream.of(input).map(classB::eval),
                              Stream.of(input).map(classC::eval)))
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .findFirst();
```

and it doesn’t scale.

It seems, the best option is to wait for Java-9 where you can use

```
Optional<Output> o = classA.eval(input)
           .or(() -> classB.eval(input))
           .or(() -> classC.eval(input));
```