# Lambda return type as generic

Tags: java-8

Could someone help me how to write lambda implementation for the following functional interface.

```
public interface InnerLambda {

    public  <R> R test(String str);

}
```

And I have a class well

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      testInner(str->"");

    }

    public static void testInner(InnerLambda innerLambda){

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588518/lambda-expression-and-generic-method

Comment: A method signature like `<R> R test(String str)` promises to return whatever type the caller likes to substitute for `R`. Your lambda expression returns a `String`, hence does not fulfill the promise. How is `testInner` supposed to know that the provided argument returns a `String` and not another `R`? In fact, it is impossible for an ordinary Java implementation to fulfill the promise, unless it always returns `null` or never completes normally. Which makes the use of such a declaration of limited use.

Comment: @Holger wait... so you can not use this a lambda expression, since the `JLS` prohibits this. But you can't use it as a method reference either. So this is one useless `@FunctionalInterface` in terms of being used for StreamAPI let's say

Comment: @Eugene you *can* use this interface with method reference to compatible generic implementation methods. But these methods have limited use.

Answer (score 0):

It's good if you will have interface like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface // Ensure if your interface have only one bastract method.
public interface InnerLambda<R> {

    public R test(String str);

}
```

There are many ways to do so one of them is given below:

```
InnerLamda innerLamda = str -> {
    //implementation will go here.
    // return the response
}
```

//You can call by using below line

int length = innerLamda.test("input");

> Lamda will identify the value of R based of value you are returning
>   from your lamda.

Edit:

if you want to do it with generic at method level then you can do it with method references as it's not supported by lamda as stated in below document:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3

method reference example is below:

```
//class_name::<type_here>method_name
lamdaFunctions::<String>process
```

> Note: If you are calling it a functional interface then what is the
>   issue in defining the generic at the interface level.because there is
>   only one abstract method.

Comment: did u happen to *try* this?

Comment: Hi.. @Shivang 
that will give you compile time error

Comment: Your edit moved the genric type parameter to the class, which does not cover the question (just like davidxxx's answer.)

Comment: Since you made the `InnerLamda` type generic, the declaration `InnerLamda innerLamda` is using a *raw type*.

Comment: Sure , we can use generic type there, I wanted to use generic type at method level instead of class level.

Comment: @KarunakarReddyL [pvpkiran’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822648/lambda-return-type-as-generic/51822757?noredirect=1#comment90599371_51822648) already linked to the answer, you can only implement such a function via method reference (to a generic method), not a lambda expression. The reason why all answers suggest a different interface is explained in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822648/lambda-return-type-as-generic/51822757?noredirect=1#comment90599946_51822648), your declaration is not very useful.

Comment: @Holger oh damn! the only way to use it would be `public static <T> T test(String s) {   return null;}; InnerLambda i = YourClass::test;` (or via an instance), but still, this very useless

Comment: @KarunakarReddyL My Question is if you are calling it as a functional interface then what is the issue in defining the generic at the interface level.because there is no abstract method another method.

Comment: Please refer this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588518/lambda-expression-and-generic-method

Comment: @Eugene don't forget `<T> T example2(String s) { throw new RuntimeException(); }` or `<T> T example3(String s) { for(;;); }`, but still, not much useful. (There are a few possible implementation scenarios outside the Java language, e.g. Lombok)

Comment: @Eugene You have to declare generic type in your method refernce: YourClass::<String>test; like this,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use lambda expression for a functional interface with a generic method scoped.

Your interface functional would make more sense by being generic :

```
public interface InnerLambda<R> {    
    R test(String str);    
}
```

Here are some examples.

To concatenate the String param to another String :

```
InnerLambda<String> l1 = s -> s + "other string";
```

To return a boolean according to the String param nullity :

```
InnerLambda<Boolean> l2 = Objects::nonNull;
```

Comment: no no, this is *not* about how it would make sense or not. did not down vote btw ;)

Comment: @Eugene Reworded. I didn't know this thing. I read the referenced dup.