# Why does overriding this generic method only work if the base method includes an unused type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I've encountered a rather weird thing while working on my Java project.

I have this base method in an `interface`:

```
public interface Registry<T extends FlakeType<? extends F>, F extends Flake> {

    @Nullable
    public <E extends F> T findType(@Nonnull String name);
}
```

Obviously the type parameter `E` is completely useless since it is neither used in the return type nor the arguments. My IDE also notifies me about that.

And I have another interface extending `Registry`:

```
public interface EntityRegistry extends Registry<EntityType<? extends Entity>, Entity> {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    <E extends Entity> EntityType<E> findType(@Nonnull String name);

}
```

For context, `Entity` extends `Flake`, `EntityType<E extends Entity>` extends `FlakeType<E>`.

As you can see I am attemting to specify the return type of this method from `EntityType<? extends Entity>` (this type is coming from the `T` type parameter) to `EntityType<E>`, while `E` is a method type parameter `<E extends Entity>`.

Logically, `? extends Entity` and `E extends Entity` mean the same thing in this case since `E` has no other restrictions or something like that and because of this acts essentially also as a wildcard for types extending `Entity`.

This works perfectly fine.

---

*However*, ive noticed the notification by my IDE (Intellij) that

> Type parameter `E` is never used.

This made me think that I could remove it since it is obviously useless and does not have any relationship to either the return value or any argument.

The overriding method provides its own `E` type parameter which should in no way have something to do with a useless type parameter with the same name in the base method. *Or has it?*

Because once I changed my base method to this:

```
@Nullable
    public T findType(@Nonnull String name);
```

overriding it the same way was no longer possible:

> `findType(String)` in `EntityRegistry` clashes with
>   `findType(String)` in `Registry`; both methods have same erasure, yet
>   neither overrides the other.

---

My questions are now:

- Why does Java require a useless type parameter in the base method when
  an overriding method wants to specify the return values generic type? Shouldn't the parameter provided by the overriding method be sufficient?
- Why does overriding in the second case NOT work? Shouldn't it work because the signature is exactly equal to the first case, except that instead of the explicit wildcard another type parameter is used, but since that does mean the same thing, what is the difference?

I am sure I have made some wrong assumptions about generics and this is why I am confused by this. Could you clear it up for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type parameters are part of the method signature. You can find this in [JLS §8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, **the same type parameters (if any)** ([§8.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method `m2` if either:
>
> - `m2` has the same signature as `m1`, or
> - the signature of `m1` is the same as the erasure ([§4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)) of the signature of `m2`.
>
> Two method signatures `m1` and `m2` are *override-equivalent* iff either `m1` is a subsignature of `m2` or `m2` is a subsignature of `m1`.

Without the type parameter in `Registry`, the method in `EntityRegistry` does not have a subsignature of the base interface method, so it is not seen as an override.

Answer (score 1):

See [answer by Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51995054/5221149) for full description of why it fails to compile:

> Type parameters are part of the method signature.

To make it compile, simply specify method in `EntityRegistry` as:

```
@Nullable
@Override
EntityType<? extends Entity> findType(@Nonnull String name);
```

That is consistent with the original version, since `E` really is undefined, i.e. `?`.

Comment: Good answer @Andreas. But 
„*Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards*“ — ([*The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Generics (Updated)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html))

Answer (score 1):

Valid override - the signature of the `findType` method is the same in both interfaces:

```
<E>findType(String name)
```

Invalid override - the signature becomes different because of the removal of a type parameter `E`:

```
<E>findType(String name)

findType(String name)
```

JLS [§8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) and [§8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) describe overriding rules and the role of the method signature in them.

Answer (score 1):

A significant part of the problem with your original code, is it is unnecessarily complicated. Also, there would be no way to implement your original *`EntityRegistry.findType()`* without settling for an unchecked cast...

```
...warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
         return ( EntityType< E > ) new EntityType< >(  new Entity( name ) );
                                    ^
  required: EntityType<E>
  found:    EntityType<Entity>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Entity declared in method <E>findType(String)
1 warning
```

Even worse still, because *`EntityRegistry.findType()`* is a generic method, [*it can't be used as a lambda*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22588738).

Here is [*a much simpler, more type-safe solution*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_296114):

```
interface Registry< T extends FlakeType<? extends Flake> > {

    T findType(String name);
}
```

```
interface EntityRegistry< U extends EntityType<? extends Entity> > extends Registry<U> {

    @Override
    U findType(String name);
}
```

The successfully compiling, correctly running implementation in the above link works this way...

```
...
EntityRegistry<EntityType<Entity>> registry = (name) -> { return new EntityType<Entity>(new Entity(name)); };
...
```

and this way...

```
...
Registry<EntityType<Entity>> registry = (name) -> { return new EntityType<Entity>(new Entity(name)); };
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this old question, the codebase I originally asked this question for is long retired by now (I went an entirely different way in the end with this issue), but this is incredibly useful to me right now due to a different project :)