# Java: How to rewrite using Lamda -- where an Exceptions can be thrown

Tags: java

How can I rewrite this via a Java Lambda?

**This question is different from "Lambda Expression and generic method" issue. The issue is because of throwing an Exception.**

```
public Observable<String> getUserInfo() {
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
            try {
                emitter.onNext( getPlayerInfo());
                emitter.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

When I rewrite this via a normal Lambda, then I get this error:

> Incompatible types: Required: Observable <java.lang.String>. Found:
>   Observable <java.lang.Object>.

This is what I tried:

```
public Observable<String> getUserInfo() {
    return Observable.create( emitter -> {
            try {
                emitter.onNext(getPlayerInfo();
                emitter.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda Expression and generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588518/lambda-expression-and-generic-method)

Comment: Why do you *want* to, though?  I see no difference in perceived readability or ceremony between the two forms.

Comment: Lambda's not always improving the readability of the code. I agree. In this case it is more concise. Only the business logica is shown, no ceremony stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inference engine of the compiler cannot determine the type parameter of `Observable`, so you need to explicitly specify it:

```
return Observable.<String>create( emitter -> {
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Type inference fails specifically because of the trailing calls to subscribeOn and observeOn. Another solution is introducing an intermediate method or variable, for example:

```
private Observable<String> getUserInfo() {
    Observable<String> userInfo = Observable.create( emitter -> {
            try {
                emitter.onNext(getPlayerInfo();
                emitter.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        });

    return userInfo
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```